# How to add allow punctuation with sql

Tags: html, mysql, sql, syntax, punctuation

I am receiving a syntax error when typing punctuation into my website form such as ' or &. I am using the below code on the page when receiving this error. What am I missing or doing wrong that will fix this issue?

```
$name=$_REQUEST["title"];
$stdate=$_REQUEST["sdate"];
$endate=$_REQUEST["edate"];
$staddr=$_REQUEST["staddr"];
$addr2=$_REQUEST["staddr2"];
$city=$_REQUEST["city"];
$state=$_REQUEST["state"];
$zip=$_REQUEST["zip"];
$desc=$_REQUEST["desc"];
$file=$_REQUEST['photo'];
$link=$_REQUEST["link"];
$user=$_REQUEST["user"];
/***************** DELETE QUERY ****************************/
$date2 = date('Y-m-d');
$qry = "DELETE FROM table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`endate`, '%Y-%m-%d') <  '".$date2."'";
$del = mysql_query($qry); 
$query = "INSERT INTO table (fname,stdate,endate,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip,name,size,type,content,link,description,user) VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "','$stdate','$endate','" . mysql_real_escape_string($staddr) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($addr2) . "','$city','$state','$zip','".str_replace(' ','',$name)."-".$stdate."-".$file.".png','0',' ',' ','" . mysql_real_escape_string($link)."','" . mysql_real_escape_string($desc) . "','$user')";

$q2=mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'. mysql_error());
if($q2) {
echo "ok"; 
} else {
echo "error ".$query.mysql_error();
}   

?>
```

The issue stems from the query line

Comment: add `mysql_real_escape_string()`...you get the values by submitting a form? better use `$_POST['']`

Comment: @SamTengWong Where would you suggest exactly? I tried that and the photo no longer appears.

Comment: `$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);`... you save the photo on your db?.. `$_REQUEST` contains `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` variables...

Comment: This is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: @SamTengWong the method you gave me saves the photo, but now the punctuation shows as wilson\'s instead of wilson's

Comment: @SamTengWong the issue is here: ".str_replace(' ','',$name)."-".$stdate."-".$file.".png with the file name.